# How to display 2 timezones on Mac Outlook 365?

Tags: mac, outlook-365

I live in New York (EST) and my boss lives in Oregon (PST).

I am constantly having meetings in different timezones and wanted to see if I could add 2 timezones to my Microsoft Outlook 365 account so I can 'at a glance' see the time difference.

Is this even possible/supported by Outlook 365 for Mac?

Comment: OS shouldn't make a difference. That's part of the point of using a web app.